# Sending email on form submit

Tags: php, html

I would like users to be able to submit feedback in something like the simple form below, and then when they press submit it sends the feedback to my email address. My hope is to have the subject line automatically be "Feedback from [whatever they put in the name input]" and to have the email say it's sent from whatever they put in the email input if that's possible.

```
<p>Name<p>
 <input class="text">
<p>Email<p>
 <input class="text">
<p>Feedback<p>
 <textarea rows="12"></textarea>
 <input class="btn" type="submit">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mail('your@email.com', 'Feedback From ' . $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'], 'From: ' . $_POST['email']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: With respect to the original HTML form, OP's <input> fields need to have a name attribute